# La phrase « qui sont à l’origine celles... » renvoie-t-elle aux « signes de rejet » ou aux « hypothèses de travail » ?

Tags: sens

Dans ce passage :

> Les signes de rejet à l’égard de l’Occident qui se manifestent si souvent au moins dans le discours, le poids des études, des recherches, des méthodes d’investigation, des hypothèses de travail, qui sont à l’origine celles des Occidentaux à propos du Maroc, restent énormes.

La phrase « qui sont à l’origine celles... »  renvoie-t-elle aux « signes de rejet » ou plutôt aux « hypothèses de travail » ?

Comment: Il s'agit probablement d'une erreur de traduction, cela n'a pas vraiment de sens.

Comment: @stbr cette phrase me semble tout à fait compréhensible, en quoi n'a-t-elle pas de sens ?

Comment: @LaurentS La ponctuation est mal placée, si l'on relit plusieurs fois on peut en comprendre un sens (je dis un parce que je ne sais même pas si c'est celui voulu)...

Answer (score 1):

Selon moi "celles" se réfère ici à la fois aux études, méthodes, recherches et hypothèses. Comme tous ces noms sont féminins, "celles" s'impose. Et si dans l'énumération on avait par exemple placé "rapports", on aurait employé "ceux".

Je pense aussi, si cela peut aider la compréhension de la phrase, que "restent" s'applique à la fois aux signes et au "poids" (de toutes ces choses qui sont à l'origine celles des occidentaux à propos du Maroc)

Comment: "Celles" ne peut avoir comme antécédent "signes", du genre masculin, et se référe ou bien à "hypothèses" ou bien à  "études, méthodes, recherches et hypothèses", c'est au choix.  "Restent" ne peut que se référer à "signes", sujet de la phrase.  Mais, mon Dieu, que tout cela est mal écrit!  Je plains les directeurs de cette thèse non publiée.

Comment: Je vous l'accorde, c'est plutôt mal écrit car sinon nous n'aurions pas toutes ces discussions et possibles significations différentes.

Answer (score -2):

Comme « signe » est masculin, « celles » ne peut pas renvoyer à « signe » ; donc ce démonstratif renvoie soit à « hypothèses » soit à « méthodes » et « hypothèses » en admettant qu'il n'y a pas de logique dans l'idée que les études et les recherches pourraient être occidentales ; telle quelle la formulation n'est pas claire.

reformulation claire

*les deux, bien qu'il soit assez difficile de concevoir qu'il pourrait exister des méthodes occidentales d'investigation à propos du Maroc*

- Les signes de rejet à l’égard de l’Occident qui se manifestent si souvent au moins dans le discours, le poids des études, des recherches, des méthodes d’investigation, des hypothèses de travail, méthodes et hypothèses étant à l’origine celles des Occidentaux à propos du Maroc, restent énormes.

*hypothèses*

- Les signes de rejet à l’égard de l’Occident qui se manifestent si souvent au moins dans le discours, le poids des études, des recherches, des méthodes d’investigation, et des hypothèses de travail, ces hypothèses étant à l’origine celles des Occidentaux à propos du Maroc, restent énormes.

Il y a autre chose qui n'est pas clair ; qu'est-ce que signifie réellement « un rejet qui se manifeste dans le poids des … » ? Ne serait-ce pas plutôt « un rejet qui se manifeste dans **l'estimation (par les marocains)** du poids des … » ?

> (TLFi) estimation  B. Au fig. Jugement (favorable ou défavorable) par lequel on détermine, marque la valeur que l'on attribue (ou doit attribuer) à telle personne ou à telle chose abstraite.